# Gstreamer pipeline to concat two media containers (video and audio streams)

Tags: video, concatenation, gstreamer

I am a beginner to gstreamer and struggling with a pipeline for Gstreamer 1.0 to concatenate seamlessly two MP4 media containers, both of them with video and audio streams. 
It seems to me that using "concat" element is the most convenient way, and I am able to concat either video streams:

```
gst-launch-1.0 concat name=c ! autovideosink  filesrc location=1.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! c.  filesrc location=2.mp4 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! c.
```

or audio streams:

```
gst-launch-1.0 concat name=c ! autoaudiosink  filesrc location=1.mp4 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! c.  filesrc location=2.mp4 ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! c.
```

but no luck so far with creating a pipeline which concatenates both containers with video and audio.

From [this article](https://coaxion.net/blog/2014/08/concatenate-multiple-streams-gaplessly-with-gstreamer/) I realized that [streamsynchronizer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-plugins/html/gst-plugins-base-plugins-streamsynchronizer.html) is required for that, so could someone please help with sample pipeline showing how it might look like ?

Comment: What do you mean by "no luck so far"? This pipeline works for me and I get a continuous play of two mp4 videos: `gst-launch-1.0 concat name=c ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! autovideosink  filesrc location=video1.mp4 ! decodebin ! c. filesrc location=video2.mp4 ! decodebin ! c.`

Comment: @EzequielGarcia yes it works.. but he needs to have audio in same pipe as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I came up with this but sometimes the alsa says that the stream is not in a proper state..

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 concat name=c2 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! autovideosink concat name=c ! audioconvert ! audiorate ! alsasink filesrc location=big.mp4 ! decodebin name=d1 ! audio/x-raw ! queue ! c. filesrc location=big2.mp4 ! decodebin name=d2 ! audio/x-raw ! queue ! c. d1. ! video/x-raw ! queue ! c2. d2. ! video/x-raw ! queue ! c2.
```

Little info to the pipe:

1, You dont have to use audioconvert/videoconvert to recognize the type of stream from decodebin - you can safely use `audio/x-raw` or `video/x-raw` respectively.. after decoding the audio/video is always in raw format.

2, use 2 concat elements as one can only handle one stream at time.. but if you use two concats you may fear that audio/video is not synchronized.. I hope it is synced as they both live in same pipe which has one clock provider for everything so theoreticaly it should be ok.. its always important to have everything in one pipe when you need proper synchronization.

3, I used alsasink but you may use whatever sink suits you.. sometimes the autoaudiosink picked pulsesink for me which I do not like very much.. I like to use this kind of audio end of pipe: `audioconvert ! audiorate ! alsasink`

4, I have seen these errors but after adding queue it went away.. but they may appear for you I dont know..

```
0:00:00.053972316 11839 0x7f0274003b70 WARN           audiobasesink gstaudiobasesink.c:1139:gst_audio_base_sink_wait_event:<alsasink0> error: Sink not negotiated before eos event.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSink:alsasink0: The stream is in the wrong format.
Additional debug info:
gstaudiobasesink.c(1139): gst_audio_base_sink_wait_event (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAlsaSink:alsasink0:
Sink not negotiated before eos event.
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
```

Comment: Thank a lot! It works! Could you please also give an example of a pipeline which muxes the output into mp4 and writes to a filesink ?

Comment: hmm.. maybe you really need the streamsynchronizer, I havent read the whole question.. to the mp4 muxing - you would need to reencode audio/video and use mp4mux and reencode with avenc_eac3 and x264enc.. either update the question or make a new one (and post comment that you did..)

Comment: that pipeline syntax is a black magic to me - played with it few more hours, apparently my knowledge is not enough to solve it by myself, hence posted [the next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416015/gstreamer-write-both-video-and-audo-streams-into-a-single-mp4-container-after-c)

Comment: @KanstantinKachanouski yeah I know exactly how you feel.. but once you gasp few things you will produce megabytes of gst-launch code ;D I will check the new question.. its good to ask new question if its quite different from original one